# Find match in two arrays of objects where most keys match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to reconcile 2 lists of contacts and in so doing realized that the newer list may have changes which should be applied to the older list and am trying to figure out how to find these matches.  I have two arrays of objects representing contacts.  The first is my current list of contacts and the second is a list of possible new contacts.  The new contacts may have matches to the current contacts. These matches, however, may have an item or two changed, such as Address and Phone Number.  Even names may change.  Is there a way to compare the two arrays and if X out of Y key values for a given object match and know which two match?

```
  var currentClients = [
    {id:1, name:'Sarah maiden', email:'sarah@sampleemail.send', phone: 12345, address:'123 My Address Way', birthday:'1/2/1980'},
    {id:2, name:'Mark', email:'mark@sampleemail.send', phone: 97678, address:'582 My Address Way'},
    {id:3, name:'Mike', email:'mike@sampleemail.send', phone: 86468, address:'3646 My Address Way'},
    {id:4, name:'Susan', email:'special@sampleemail.send', phone: 68426, address:'4 My Address Way'},
    {id:5, name:'Tiffany', email:'yayt@sampleemail.send', phone: 2672, address:'9 My Address Way'},
    {id:6, name:'Pat', email:'hey@sampleemail.send', phone: 1622, address:'628962 My Address Way'},
    {id:7, name:'Buddy', email:'mahbud@sampleemail.send', phone: 27269, address:'25 My Address Way'}
  ];

  var newClients = [
    {id:11, name:'Sarah married', email:'sarah@sampleemail.send', phone: 12345, address:'123 My Address Way'},
    {id:12, name:'Bloke', email:'bloke@sampleemail.send', phone: 5555, address:'628962 Different Address Way'},
    {id:13, name:'Harry', email:'harry@sampleemail.send', phone: 2222, address:'3646 Different Address Way', birthday:'12/22/2002'},
    {id:14, name:'Sally', email:'meg@sampleemail.send', phone: 3333, address:'4 Different Address Way', birthday:'12/21/2002'},
    {id:15, name:'Larry', email:'wait@sampleemail.send', phone: 4444, address:'9 Different Address Way'},
    {id:16, name:'Mark', email:'mark@sampleemail.send', phone: 111, address:'582 NEW Way'},
    {id:17, name:'Paul', email:'niceguy@sampleemail.send', phone: 6666, address:'25 Different Address Way'}
  ];
```

Using the arrays above I want to loop through the newClients and know when (if) one matches all but two of the name, email, phone, address, and/or birthday keys with the currentClients.  A function could return the currentClient object or index.  Note that some keys, such as birthday, may not have a value so these would be ignored if one is missing a value but used otherwise.

I thought about matching one of any of these except I know I have clients sharing some of these, such as email, address, phone.  I want a record for each of these persons so just matching one item will not work as anything that may not be shared is easily changed (names - married/divorced, etc) or a contrived item (their id) with no meaning outside the code and no actual tie between the two.

So in the above arrays I am looking to match the object having ID 1 with the object having ID 11 and ID 2 with ID 16 in my samples. My ultimate goal would be to change the Current items which are different to match the New values.  Once I have this match and know which current item to edit with which new item I can handle the rest.  Yes, I am also adding the non-matching items, but that part is easy.  If not for these possible changed values I would be done.  I have done some searching to figure this out but I think I am not using proper terms as I have not found an answer.  I thought maybe some array.filter() but am still not wrapping my head around matching all but two of the following

Comment: tldr. let's migrate them to database and tell it also to maintain such priority :)

Answer (score 0):

http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html 
please refer this article. you need to compare values of objects.

Comment: Except I want to know when a few of a group of keys from an object in one array match the same keys from another object in a second array.   I can compare values of one or more keys and know they all match.  I want to know when some of them match, and how many, or know if a given number of them match.  I guess a kind of fuzzy match?  I may be misusing the term fuzzy,